# How to choose random value from array, then choose randomly again excluding the value just chosen?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am trying to create a combination of unique phrases to make a sentence and want to randomly select a phrase length from S (only needs to happen 1 time), and then randomly select first a J value, and then a random Q value, but I do not want the same value selected from J or S selected. How can I do this?

Here is what some of the sample outputs look like:

I3 and I1
I4 not I5
I5 or I4 and I3 not I3

```
Q=("but","why","okay")
J=("J1","J2","J3","J4","J5")
S=[(J), (J,Q,J), (J,Q,J,Q,J),(J,Q,J,Q,J,Q,J)]

' '.join([random.choice(i) for i in random.choice(S)])
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `(J)` (which is same as `J`) or `(J,)` (which is a one-element tuple, similar to `(J, Q, J)`?

Comment: Wait no, good catch. I would just want one value for J put out there, not all of the values! Would I just do J(1)? Or J(i)?

Comment: I know that. What I'm saying is that you probably wanted to make a 1-tuple there, just like you have a 3-tuple, a 5-tuple and a 7-tuple in the rest of the list, for consistency. `(J)` is not a 1-tuple, it's just `J` in parentheses. To make a 1-tuple, you need the extra comma. If not, then the code gets complicated as you need to handle the first element as an exception to the rule (all elements of S are tuples).

Comment: Ahh thank you a ton sir! I see what you're saying! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle both arrays, then take elements as you need, one by one. Or sample them, if you don't want to have the originals perturbed:

```
Q=("but","why","okay")
J=("J1","J2","J3","J4","J5")
S=[(J,), (J,Q,J), (J,Q,J,Q,J), (J,Q,J,Q,J,Q,J)]

from random import sample, choice
from collections import Counter

seq = choice(S)
iters = { s: iter(sample(s, c)) for s, c in Counter(seq).items() }
result = ' '.join(next(iters[s]) for s in seq)
```

So I pick the desired sequence first. Then I count how many times does each list appear in the chosen sequence. Then, for each unique list, I take as many random elements (without repetition) as there are appearances of the list in the sequence, then make an iterator for those choices, so I can get them one by one. The last thing left to do is to iterate over the sequence, and take the next element from the appropriate iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps

```
result = []
temp = S
while temp is not empty:
   random1 = random.choice(temp)
   value = random.choice(random1)
   result.append(value)
   temp2 = random1.remove(value)
   temp = temp.remove(random1)
   if temp2 is not empty:
      temp = temp.append(temp2)

print(' '.join(result))
```

The key idea is that we will remove the chosen value before the next random